# Calculate Inductance of a three phase transmission line

Tags: power-supply, power, mains, three-phase, inductance

[image]

I was trying to solve the above problem. As I have done many similar problems, I attempted it in the following way

[image]

But I was shocked when I checked the solution given in my workbook.

[image]

[image]

Please help me to understand this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coupling of other phases tends to oppose to induction of each phase slightly.  You are close.

Comment: Sir, why my method is wrong ? Is it a special case ?

Comment: You neglected phase shift of other 2 currents coupled into each at +\- 120 deg

Comment: Yes, I assumed Ia =Ib = Ic. I will go through the derivation once again.

Comment: Yes it is I(t) for ABC